# Apply JS functions to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to use the same JavaScript and AJAX code for multiple paragraph elements. I need to get the contents (innerHTML) of the paragraph as this is the input parameter for my PHP. But as you can see the code relies on the id or class name of the p tag. I know it works with just one example. How do I make it work for many examples? Here is the code

```
<style>
#popup-header, #popup-body{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;     
    visibility:hidden;
}
#popup-body{
    height:270px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-radius:0 0 6px 6px;
}
#popup-header{
    height:30px;
    width:300px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    color:white;
    background-color:#0000CC;
    border-radius;6px 6px 0 0;
}
#popup{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#CCC
    visibility:hidden;
    border-radius;6px 6px 0 0;

}
</style>
<body>
<script>
function mOut(obj) {
    //obj.innerHTML = myElement.innerHTML; 
    document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("popup-header").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("popup-body").style.visibility = 'hidden';
}

function mOver(obj) {
  var myElement = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for modern browsers
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("popup").style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById("popup-header").style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById("popup-body").style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.getElementById("popup-header").innerHTML =     myElement.innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("popup-body").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getVerse.php?q="+myElement.innerHTML, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<p class="demo" onmouseout="mOut(this)" onmouseover="mOver(this)">Matthew 5:12</p>
<p class="demo" onmouseout="mOut(this)" onmouseover="mOver(this)">Matthew 5:13</p>
<div id="popup">
    <div id="popup-header"></div>
    <div id="popup-body"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
var myElement = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
```

with

```
var myElement = obj;
```

since you are already passing the `Element` object on which event is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your function so that it takes the innerHTML of the current element as an argument and call it as follows: mOver(this.innerHTML).

Answer (score -2):

This is precisely the type of thing jQuery was designed for.

You can select your paragraph objects and then call a `foreach` on them.

```
$('P').each(function() {
   var innerHTML = $(this).html();
   //dostuff
});
```